# How to send Referenced Libraries along with my project

Tags: eclipse

I exported my project into JAR files. I also found my project folder and zipped it. 
However, I can't find referenced libraries in it.  When I send my project to someone, I want that person to get referenced libraries as well.

Can anyone tell me how I can include my referenced libraries along with my project?

[screenshot of my eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTWe2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'File > Export' and choose 'Java > Runnable JAR file' to generate a Jar which contains your code and the referenced libraries.